# Display error message when shortcode user entry id not added

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I have this shortcode ( put together from different sources ) and it works.. when a user inputs the shortcode to a page [insert_xpage idnum="123"] it will show the contents of the page id123.

However if in the shortcode itself when a user inputs the shortcode and does not add the id number **[insert_xpage idnum=""]** the site dies. NOT the backend, just the frontend. You can navigate to the shortcode on the post and enter a number and the site comes back.

I have added a var called $err containing an error message with some html markup also shown below.

How can the **$output = '';**  be amended to show the error, instead of killing the page? and... *still allow the site to work!*

```
    But have a little error message where the $output should be?
```

**Maybe another filter? or some kind of elseif? don't know....**

I had tried to do different output, return, echo or just different ways to show an error

tried:

.$GLOBALS["err"].

' ".$GLOBALS["err"]." '

echo "".$GLOBALS["err"]."";

echo ""$err"";

If a user does not add the required id in the correct place, the site itself breaks.

```
    EG: [insert_xpage idnum=""]
    instead of [insert_xpage idnum="123"]
```

Comment: Shortcode should always return value. Not directly `echo`.

Comment: I figured that out the hard way....

Comment: Yes, the $output will only render the data - however if there is none... that, I think is the issue...

Comment: Got it sorted out thanks to this:

       https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-if-else-statements.php Used an if statement